# If two real series $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ converge but $\sum a_n b_n$ does not can $\sum a_n$ or $\sum b_n$ converge absolutely?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

If two  real series $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ converge but $\sum a_n b_n$ does not can one of $\sum a_n$ or $\sum b_n$ converge absolutely?

I can show that if $\sum a_n$ converges absolutely then the partial sums of the series $a_n b_n$ are bounded, but this is equivalent to saying that the series converges only when all the terms are positive, but that is not the case if $b_n<0$.

Obviously both cannot converge absolutely because then $a_n b_n$ converges absolutely and so the series itself converges.

Comment: Try to show that if one of the two series converges absolutely, then $\sum \lvert a_n b_n\rvert < +\infty$.

Comment: No, that's not correct. In general, we have $\sum a_n b_n \neq \biggl(\sum a_n\biggr)\biggl(\sum b_n\biggr)$, and you need some other property of the sequence $(b_n)$. If $\sum b_n$ converges (not necessarily absolutely), what properties of the sequence $(b_n)$ does that imply?

Comment: That $b_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$

Comment: Okay. And that implies something else. Any guess what might help?

Comment: Maybe that the sequence ($b_n$) is bounded since if it converges it is Cauchy and if it is Cauchy it is bounded?

Comment: Ha-yup. Now, can you show that if $\sum a_n$ converges absolutely, and $(b_n)$ is bounded, then $\sum a_n b_n$ converges absolutely?

Comment: I am trying but I can't seem to think of a way forward

Comment: Pretend that all that you know about the $b_n$ is that $\lvert b_n\rvert \leqslant C$.

Comment: So then $\sum |a_n b_n| \leq \sum |a_n|C = C\sum |a_n|$ and we can use the comparison test?

Answer (score 1):

No. This is impossible. If $\sum a_{n}$ is convergent, and $\sum b_{n}$ is absolutely convergent, then $\sum a_{n}b_{n}$ converges absolutely.

Since $\sum a_{n}$ converges, then $\lim a_{n}=0$. So, the sequence $(a_{n})$
is bounded and there exists $c\geq 0$ such that $|a_{n}|\leq c$ for all $n\geq 1$.
Therefore
$$\sum |a_{n}b_{n}|\leq c \sum |b_{n}|$$ and we are done by the comparison test.
No need to worry about the constant $c$. We could start off looking at the series $\sum \frac{1}{c} a_{n}b_{n}$ and get 
$$\sum \frac{1}{c}|a_{n}b_{n}|\leq \sum |b_{n}|$$ and notice that multiplication by constant does not affect the convergence.

Comment: More generally if $(a_n)_n$ is a bounded sequence and $\sum_nb_n$ converges absolutely then $\sum_na_nb_n$ converges absolutely, regardless of whether $\sum_na_n$ converges.............+1